# How to free the memory of return value of OGRGeometry::Buffer()?

Tags: polygon, buffer, ogr, memory

I have in C++ (gdal 2.3.2)

```
OGRPolygon poly;
OGRGeometry* geom = poly.Buffer(1e-12, 1);
```

now how do I free the memory allocated for `geom` after done using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use C++ function:

```
OGRGeometryFactory::destroyGeometry( geom );
```

or C API function:

```
OGR_G_DestroyGeometry((OGRGeometryH)geom);
```